# Get generated checkbox id in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Attempting to get generated checkbox ID

Current checkbox code

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_select"  type="checkbox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);" />
```

Generated:

```
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_reminderList_CheckBox_select_10" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl12$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);">

<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_reminderList_CheckBox_select_11" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl11$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);">
```

How to get ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_reminderList_CheckBox_select_10 & ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_reminderList_CheckBox_select_11 in javascript or even in asp.net?

Comment: When you want to get the `ID`

Answer (score 0):

> Read `Element.id` property

```js
function CheckCheckBox(elem) {
  console.log(elem.id);
}
```

```html
<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_reminderList_CheckBox_select_10" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl12$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);">

<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView_reminderList_CheckBox_select_11" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView_reminderList$ctl11$CheckBox_select" onclick="javascript:CheckCheckBox(this);">
```

Comment: Thank You! Was having lots of trouble in this.